# Is there a way to obtain the keys from a deleted record?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm using PostgreSQL to save a form in three tables, one for the name and id, another one for the fields to populate, and a third to store values for the fields.

```java
private static final String REMOVE_FORM = "DELETE FROM forms WHERE name = ?";
private PreparedStatement removeFormQuery;

public boolean connect() throws SQLException{
    this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
    this.removeFormQuery = this.connection.prepareStatement(REMOVE_FORM);
}
public void close() throws SQLException {
    if(null != this.connection) {
        this.connection.close();
    }
    if(null != this.removeFormQuery) {
            this.removeFormQuery.close();
    }
}
```

```java
private void removeForm(String form) {
    try {
        removeFormQuery.setString(1, form);
        int execute = removeFormQuery.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(execute);
        ResultSet generatedKeys = removeFormQuery.getGeneratedKeys();
        while (generatedKeys.next()) {
            int anInt1 = generatedKeys.getInt("id");
            removeFieldQuery.setInt(1, anInt1);
            if (removeFieldQuery.execute())
                System.out.println("remove field failed");
            else
                System.out.println("remove field success");
            ResultSet generatedFieldsKeys = removeFieldQuery.getGeneratedKeys();
            while (generatedFieldsKeys.next()) {
                int anInt = generatedFieldsKeys.getInt("id");
                removeListItemQuery.setInt(1, anInt);
                if (removeListItemQuery.execute())
                    System.out.println("remove listItem failed");
                else
                    System.out.println("remove listItem success");
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code doesn't generate keys after the remove query is executed, am I missing something?

Comment: What's the sql of your queries and the definitions of your tables?

Comment: How exactly did you prepare the `removeFromQuery` statement? And what is the underlying SQL query you are running there. Please **[edit]** your question and add that code.

Answer (score 0):

While you haven't told us what queries you are running, if they are `delete`s then you wouldn't expect any generated keys.

From the Javadoc for `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`:

```
     * Retrieves any auto-generated keys created as a result of executing this
     * Statement object. If this Statement object did
     * not generate any keys, an empty ResultSet
     * object is returned.
```

Keys may be auto generated when you insert into a table, creating a new row which needs a primary key, but when you delete a row no key generation occurs.

Comment: "*but when you delete a row no key generation occurs.*" - unless the SQL statement contained a `returning` clause.